# eslint to detect variable/this outside of the contructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have this class implemented in a Typescript code on Node 16 and target es2019.

```
class BatchGetResponseImpl implements BatchGetResponse {
  //  eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  constructor(private result: Map<string, Iterable<any>>) {}
  readonly tableNames: Iterable<string> = this.result.keys();
  ....
}
```

When I upgrade node to 18 and the target to es2022 this doesn't work anymore.

I only get this error because one of the unit tests pass from this code. Otherwise, it usually compiles.

I was thinking.

Is it possible to write an esLint rule to alert this kind of error?
If not is there another way to detect this error before I upgrade to node 18 and es2022?

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to by *because es2022 changes the classes scope.* - the transpiled code looks to be the same for both targets on my machine.

Comment: Thankyou @CertainPerformance, I shouldn't say it. I'm not 100% sure why. I just rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this bug is described in this bug. (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50971) At this time this bug is still open.

The solution is not es2022 until the bug is merged.